# mkdir(): File exists in laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel

im trying to create new folder with session,but i found this error when the folder is already exist..
this my controller

```
$sesi = Session::get('id');
if((file_exists($sesi))&&(is_dir($sesi)))
{
  return view('belanja/gerai_ut/home_input');
}   
else
{
  //memasukan fungsi mkdir 
  mkdir ("archive_gambar\\$sesi");          
  return view('belanja/gerai_ut/home_input');
}
```

why if statement is unreadable

Comment: what do you understand from `file_exists` and `is_dir` function ?

Comment: so you want to check if "archive_gambar\{id}" exists or "{id}"?

Comment: i want to check if"archive_gambar\{id}" is exist then return view if not exist then mkdir with name {id}

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;
$path=your_desire_folder_path;

 if (!File::exists($path)) {
            mkdir(public_path($path), 0777, true);
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$path = 'archive_gambar/'. Session::get('id');

if (! is_dir($path)) {
    mkdir($path);
}

return view('belanja/gerai_ut/home_input');
```